# Как получить доступ к таблицам созданного мною нового пользователя?

Tags: sql, oracle, права-доступа

Под пользователем system создал нового пользователя Admin и дал ему привилегии на ресурсы, dba и подключение к БД. После, от имени этого пользователя создал таблицу, для примера пусть это будет таблица `T`. От пользователя system я пытался получить доступ к таблице `T`, но её для пространства system не существует, зато у Admin доступ имеется.

Как получить доступ к таблицам: изменению, редактированию и т.д., для созданного мною пользователя? Можно-ли установить этот доступ автоматически, чтобы для каждого созданного пользователя, пользователь, создавший его, мог получить доступ к его таблицам?

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, как вы пытаетесь обратится к таблице "T"? И system, и вновь созданый пользователь "Admin", имеют достаточно привилегий для доступа ко всем таблицам БД, ничего делать не надо.

Comment: @0xdb, Да, конечно! Делаю следующее: в блоке кода pl/sql прописываю создание таблицы "T" через "create table", выполняю commit, в блоке pl/sql команд от пользователя system я прописываю команду "select * from T", чтобы проверить наличие доступа к таблице и получаю ошибку, которая говорит, что таблица отсутствует. Эта же команда ("select * from T;) прекрасно работает у самого Admin'a. Но мне бы хотелось, как system пользователю, обладать доступом к таблицам созданных мною пользователей

Comment: `select * from Admin.T;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> пытался получить доступ к таблице "T", но её для пространства system не существует

Совершенно верно, этой таблицы в пространстве имён system (или правильней сакзать, в схеме) не существует. Без указания полного имени объекта БД, в данном случае - `Admin.T`, поиск будет только в текущей схеме. Подробней, о том, как осуществляется поиск имён в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Syntax-for-Schema-Objects-and-Parts-in-SQL-Statements.html#GUID-08B73ED6-2ABA-4737-B8A1-F7BD0456AEDB).

Как видите, привилигированные пользователи имеют полный контроль над объектами других пользователей:

```
create user u1 identified by u1
/
User U1 created.

create table u1.t (col1 int)
/
Table U1.T created.

select * from u1.t
/
no rows selected

alter table u1.t add col2 char(1) 
/
Table U1.T altered.
```

Для удобства можно создать синонимы, тогда можно обращяться без указания схемы. Но заметьте, синонимы действуют для DML, но не для DDL:

```
create public synonym t for u1.t
/
Synonym T created.

select * from t 
/
no rows selected

drop table t purge
/
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Не забудте прибраться:

```
drop user u1 cascade
/
User U1 dropped.
```